Django Rest Framework serializer simultaneously request bug
i have one view with my basics config
class base_view(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin):
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    pagination_class = generic_pagination
    permission_required = '' # assigned at each final view (children)
    raise_exception = True # avoid redirecting to backend login
    fields = '__all__'# by default brings all fields
    aliases = [] # placeholder to avoid error as some views will not need aliases
    def handle_no_permission(self):
            if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
                # If the user is authenticated, but still lacks permission, return a JSON response indicating access denied.
                return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Permission Required'}, status=403)
            else:
                # If the user is not authenticated, return a JSON response indicating login required.
                return JsonResponse({'detail': 'Login Required'}, status=401)
    def get_serializer_class(self):
            self.serializer_class = generic_serializer
            self.serializer_class.Meta.model = self.model
            self.serializer_class.Meta.fields = self.fields
            self.serializer_class.Meta.aliases = self.aliases
            return self.serializer_class
    ### filter all querysets by company and organization + ordering
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.fields == '__all__': queryset = self.model.objects.all()
        else: queryset = self.model.objects.only(*self.fields)
        ### gets user company/organization or FORCES specific company/organization (ADMIN ONLY!)
        if (self.request.query_params.get('id_com') is not None) and (self.request.user.id==id_admin):
            queryset = queryset.filter(id_company_fk=self.request.query_params.get('id_com'))
            if self.request.query_params.get('id_org') is not None:
                queryset = queryset.filter(id_organization_fk__in = self.request.query_params.get('id_org').split(','))
        else:
            queryset = queryset.filter(id_company_fk=self.request.user.profile.id_company_fk)
            ### below: filters by organization(s) IF one is specified in user's profile AND if field exists on model
            if (self.request.user.profile.id_organization_fk is not None) and (getattr(self.model, 'id_organization_fk', False) is not False):
                queryset = queryset.filter(id_organization_fk__in = self.request.user.profile.id_organization_fk.split(','))
        ord = self.request.query_params.get('ord') # gets ordering (here as it applies to all subclasses)
        if ord is not None: self.ordering = ord # overrides ordering set on inital class view
        return queryset.order_by(self.ordering)
    ### add user id, company, date inserted for all create requests (POST)
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(id_user_fk=self.request.user.id)
        serializer.save(id_company_fk=self.request.user.profile.id_company_fk)
        serializer.save(date_inserted=timezone.now())
        return serializer
    ### add user id, company, date updated for all update requests (PUT, PATCH)
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(id_user_fk=self.request.user.id)
        serializer.save(id_company_fk=self.request.user.profile.id_company_fk)
        serializer.save(date_updated=timezone.now())
        return serializer

and I have this class extends my base view
class igs_filters_view(base_view, ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    model = igs_filters
    fields = ['filter', 'alias', 'name', 'name_id']
    ordering = 'name'
    pagination_class = None
    permission_required = 'general.home_menu'
    ### overrides method to also bring id_company = 990 (filters that apply to all companies)
    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.fields == '__all__': queryset = self.model.objects.all()
        else: queryset = self.model.objects.only(*self.fields)
        queryset = queryset.filter(id_company_fk__in=[self.request.user.profile.id_company_fk, 990])
        if self.request.user.profile.id_organization_fk is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(id_organization_fk__in = list(self.request.user.profile.id_organization_fk.split(',')))\
                       | queryset.filter(id_organization_fk__isnull=True)
        ### add aditional filter to fecth only necessarry flters (for pages that don't need all of them)
        filter = self.request.query_params.get('filter')
        if filter is not None: queryset = queryset.filter(alias__in = filter.split(','))
        return queryset

this is my generic serializer called inside base_view
class generic_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = None
        fields = '__all__' # overwritten when specific fields are selected
        aliases = [] # placeholder
    ### replaces table's field names for aliases, if provided ###
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        if self.Meta.aliases == []:
            return super().to_representation(instance) ### skips if no aliases are provided
        else:
            representation = super(generic_serializer, self).to_representation(instance)
            new_rep = OrderedDict() #creates empty dict to receive new representations
            for i in range(0, len(self.Meta.fields)):
                new_rep[self.Meta.aliases[i]] = representation[self.Meta.fields[i]]
            return new_rep

but I have some issues when my API is hitted at same time by two diferrents endpoint, the serializer of the second comes with equal the first
up to the point of abse_view when I pass my variables to my genrec serializer the variables be ok
but inside the gnereci serielizer the second hit dont overwreite the variables opf the first
Example:
when hit the anomay endpoint:
[
{
"instance_num": 0,
"variable": "case_qty",
"value": "1.0000"
},
]
its ok but  when i hit my other and point at same time i give this
[
{
"instance_num": null,
"variable": null,
"value": null
},
]
same fields of anomaly
